# Can't find MySQL database with suffix .sql on 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, database, asp-classic

I have this connection string in a classic ASP application:

```
   strConn = "driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; server="&MySQLSVR&"; port="&MySQLPRT&";User="&MySQLUID&";Password="&MySQLPWD&"; Database="&MySQLDB&"; option="&MySQLOPT & ";"

   Set oconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   oconn.Open strConn
```

Where MYSQLSVR = "127.0.0.1".

However, I can't find the MySQL database (named as in MYSQLDB string). I thought MySQL databases had the .sql extension (or .txt instead) but I found no such files.

Am I doing this incorrectly, or does the database just not exist anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but a MySQL database is not just "a file", unlike a Microsoft Access database.

If you want to use it in your computer you need to install a program called [MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and configure it with a [MySQL client](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html):

- Create users with passwords
- Create databases

Once you have that up and running, you may be able to load your application database through *.sql files (given that the guy you work for has such thing, and he apparently doesn't).

Perhaps the application is hosted somewhere else and you are supposed to connect remotely?

Comment: Thank you.. yes, the application is hosted elsewhere and works fine, so i think MYSQL Server is already configured for that. What if i'd want to convert the existent database to a .mdf file?

Comment: Oh, please forget about "files". Most relational databases do not work that way. MySQL has client-server architecture and you don't manipulate files: you establish a connection with a client and send SQL commands. Now: what do you want to do exactly? Use the existing server or configure your own?

Comment: Already told you :  i'd want to take the tables, relations and data from the existing database (wherever has a file or not) and put all this in a new one (.mdf). Can't be done?

Comment: [MDF](http://filext.com/file-extension/mdf) is a file extension used by Microsoft SQL Server. I suppose you could install SQL Server and migrate your MySQL database but your application would need a full rewrite. Furthermore, the file itself would be totally useless.

Comment: Yeah, i know what a mdf file is. "A full rewrite" is exactly what i need to do. However, still the question about how to perform this migration. I guess i'll find out later... Thank you.

Comment: @kandinsky: use mysql_dump to export MySQL's data in plaintext SQL format. Then use SSMS to import those files into MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's data files are either:

```
MyISAM - *.frm, *.myd, *.myi
InnoDB: *.frm, ib_data*, ib_logfile*
```

`.sql` files are usually just the output of mysql_dump, and are text files containing literal sql commands.

Comment: Yeah, i searched for these on google and tried to find files with the previous extensions, with no result.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find any readable data files for a mysql installation.  The binary files are generally located under $MYSQL_HOME/data/mysql.

Comment: Thank you.. but How can i access this directory from the root of my website?